# Rotate an SVG element inside a <use> node

Tags: html, css, svg

I define an SVG element as such

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
     <symbol id="clock" viewBox="0 0 30 30">
        <circle class="clock_base" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" ......></circle>
         <line class="clock_hour" .....</line> 
         <line class="clock_minute" .....</line>
     </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

And it is inserted in my DOM with `<use>`

`<svg width="100%" viewBox="0 0 30 30"><use xlink:href="clock.svg#clock"></use></svg>`

I see the element so no problem there. What I wanted was to rotate the hour and minute hands independently. So I tried

```
.clock_hour {
   animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
}
```

Which does nothing.

I know my animation works because I can apply it to the `svg` and the whole thing spins, but I just want the hands to spin. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because when the browser finishes parsing your css file and try to apply styles to each declared selector, it does not see a `<line>` element with class name `clock_hour` because it is in a different file that has to be loaded, and it happens after the css file was parsed and applied, so that is why you don't see the animation running on `class_hour`. If you copy the markup in your `clock.svg` and insert it in the same page as the other `svg`, it will apply the animation correctly